# Get multiple Key/Values in Redis with Python

Tags: python, redis, get

I can get one Key/Value from Redis with Python in this way:

```
import redis
r = redis.StrictRedis(host='localhost', port=6379, db=0)
data = r.get('12345')
```

How to get values from e.g. 2 keys at the same time (with one call)?

I tried with: `data = r.get('12345', '54321')` but that does not work..

Also how to get all values based on partial key? 
e.g. `data = r.get('123*')`

Comment: You could also have a look into other redis data types that might reflect your usecase better. For example you can store a bunch of key/values at one redis key in a redis hash and get all of them with a single `r.hgetall`. https://redis.io/topics/data-types-intro#redis-hashes

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use the method `mget` to get the values of several keys in one call (returned in the same order as the keys):

```
data = r.mget(['123', '456'])
```

To search for keys following a specific pattern, use the `scan` method:

```
cursor, keys = r.scan(match='123*')
data = r.mget(keys)
```

(Documentation: https://redis-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#)

Comment: Thanks! Do you know about partial key match? `data = r.get('123*'`)

Comment: You can use `r.scan(match='123*')` to get a list of keys that match the given pattern, and then use mget afterwards.

Comment: You should better use `keys(pattern='123*')` instead of `scan`, because to fetch all marching keys you should use scan's `cursor` argument and iterate till the end.

Answer (score 2):

As @atn says: (and if using django)

```
from django_redis import get_redis_connection

r = get_redis_connection()
data = r.keys('123*')
```

works now.

Answer (score 0):

with Django, you can directly do this that works for redis and other cache backends :

```
cache_results = cache.get_many(
    (
        cache_key_1,
        cache_key_2,
    )
)
cache_result_1 = cache_results.get(cache_key_1)
cache_result_2 = cache_results.get(cache_key_2)
```